# Implementation of state-of-the-art video shot boundary detection

Tags: image-processing, video, computer-vision, computer-science, video-processing

I am working on a wide project involving object retrieval from videos.

According to "[A Survey on Visual Content-Based Video Indexing and Retrieval](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5729374&tag=1)", most popular methods are divided in:

- simple "threshold based approach" (global or adaptative)
- supervised learning-based classifiers (with SVM or AdaBoost)
- unsupervised learning-based algorithm (mainly K-Means)

For the moment I implemented on my own a very simple and old-fashioned method based on differences of color-histograms among successive frames.

Nevertheless, I would like to try something more efficient and up to date, without spending too much time, considering that shot boundary detection is not the main topic of my research.

Does anybody know an implementation of an effective algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following implementation extremely useful and effective in my own research:

https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect

The workhorse of the codebase happens here:

https://github.com/johmathe/Shotdetect/blob/master/src/film.cc#L117-237

It mostly relies on color information for detection of shots.

Comment: I am evaluating the segmentation performance right now but it looks like it suits my case :)
I took a look at the code, and it really resembles the very simple implementation I did, it just operates in YUV space instead of RGB.
I also appreciate the single threshold.

Do you know if there is some paper involved?
Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: What you gain in boundary accuracy, you usually end up losing in speed, so simple thresholds on colors are actually quite common. I don't believe there's a related paper for the code to my knowledge. Glad it helped some at least. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Computing Chi-Square distance of RGB histograms of adjacent frames is one of the fast, simple and robust methods for shot boundary detection. You can see my implementation and usage of this method in [here](https://github.com/yasinyildirim/ShotDetection).